# Using TPM for full disc encryption?

Tags: cryptography, linux, disk-encryption

E.g.: Can I make a better full disc encryption with e.g.: LUKS using the TPM? How?

Comment: The title doesn't match your core question, so I changed it.  For more on TPM status and deployment see [Status of Trusted Computing and Remote Attestation deployment - IT Security - Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/status-of-trusted-computing-and-remote-attestation-deployment)

Comment: I'll share a link to my answer of the same question:

http://security.stackexchange.com/a/24660/16522

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With TPMCrypt: https://www.tpmcrypt.org/trac

Comment: Would you please elaborate? Even looking at the link you provided it is not easy to discern what TPM is.

Comment: @this.josh unfortunately I don't have much time at this period to write extended posts, but I've provided a related answer before, here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4008/status-of-trusted-computing-and-remote-attestation-deployment/4013#4013

Comment: @this.josh, I doubt @john's answer was intended to explain what TPM is - if you want to read the basics, head over to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module... If @john did put a tutorial in his answer it would have been edited out, anyway ;)

Comment: @AviD I looked at Wikipedia yesterday, as well as other search results. My understanding is that TPM is an architecture with a trusted hardware anchor. TPMCrypt appears to be an open source Linux based set of utilities and libraries. It references truecrypt but I can't tell if truecrypt is required. I can't tell what hardware it requires, and I assume it needs a trusted hardware anchor. I can't tell if it works with BIOS or EFI/UEFI. The most useful document I found appears to be in German, which I don't know. It looks to be of alpha status, so this seems to be a theoritical solution.

Comment: @this.josh, fair enough, and I dont claim to know much about TPMCrypt - I was just referring to TPM, as per your comment...

Comment: @AviD You are right. My intent wasn't obvious. I guess I should have asked; What is the relationship of TPMCrypt to TPM, and how does it improved disk encryption over LUKS.