# Cryptsetup using TPM?

Tags: encryption

Does cryptsetup uses TPM? or CPUID to identify the hardware environment in order to prevent it from stealing and crack it on other PC.

Comment: Also related : http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/using-tpm-for-full-disc-encryption

Comment: jyki - please re-read the [about] page. All but one of your questions have been closed, and a re-read of the guidance there should help you.