# How to protect from copying files?

Tags: file-encryption, file-access

Is possible to protect files from being copied if you are the administrator of a machine? I heard that this behaviour is possible: one software developer sells his software in such a way. He installs it on every client's computer to prevent the software from working on other computers or to prevent it from being physically copied. How can this type of copy-protection be implemented? Is it cost-effective to implement if the software only costs about $100 for all copies to be deployed across the client's company?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a problem that cryptography can solve.  This is problem that can only be addressed with the Operating System's Access Control by removing read privileges to the file.

Or put another way,  [DRM is a fundamentally flawed](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4637/485) approach,  and **will never work**.

Answer (score 3):

You can not prevent to copy a program if it is executable, because executing a program means copying it into the memory of the computer. But you can use software and hardware [dongles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongle). Simple dongles use the MAC address of the computer.