# Tutorial Video Protection on a Tablet

Tags: drm, video

I am planning to start tutorial videos.  I thought of buying a tablet and then putting the videos on the tablet.  My major concern is that the students shouldn't be able to copy the videos. They should only be able to watch the videos. They shouldn't be able to screen record the tablet too.  I want my videos to be watched by only the students who buy it.

Could anybody help me out with this?

Comment: Anytime you display a copy of something to a users eyes, it can be copied at that point. This is a fundamental problem with DRM the MPAA has thrown massive amounts of money at attempted solutions without success.

Comment: Unless you are major distributor, you won't be able to license such technology which is complex and requires 3rd party license server as well encryption engine.

Comment: Highly related (but maybe not a duplicate because of the PC v Tablet difference): http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122279/how-to-prevent-illegal-file-transfer-or-copying-of-video-files-from-a-pc

Answer (score 1):

You should try the kiosk mode of the tablet of your choice. This will lower the risk that your students will be able to copy the files from the device.

To avoid tampering you could seal your devices. Sure they still would be able to break into the device but at least you would be able to sue them afterwards if the seal is broken.

Last you wont be able to protect the content to be recorded by a second device.