# Is deploying a web application to a customer's encrypted drive a secure solution against code theft?

Tags: encryption, python, ubuntu, docker, luks

I have developed a web service for customer. The web service is written in Python and running in Docker containers. It is managed by `docker compose`.

The customer wants my web service to run on their own Ubuntu servers, but I have control over those servers. I can reinstall them, manage them, and only I know the login credentials. Likewise, I run the web service as well, not them. They only have physical access. If they're fair, they won't try to steal my code, but if they're not, I'm wondering how to guard my source code.

One option might be to encrypt the disk (for example, LUKS encryption when installing Ubuntu) and Dropbear SSH for remote disk decryption. But if I understand correctly, the moment the disk is decrypted and the web service is running, someone with Live USB Ubuntu can get to the data.

If this is true, what are the other options?

Comment: "Dropbear SSH for remote disk decryption" how would you do that? What is the setup that you're thinking involving disk encryption and remote decryption?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does DRM stop copying?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/97964/how-does-drm-stop-copying)

Answer (score -1):

Its a complicated question since the customer is the owner of the drive. I do not know if he would give permision to you encrypt his drive. Furthermore, depending of the country it would not work well for legal questions.
Its better to you save your code, with the new merges, in a public repository, like github itself, so you can prove you are the code author.
And you can request the customer to sign contract terms, where can be explicity you are the owner of the code.